# Passing a function as props in Next.js

Tags: next.js, react-hook-form

I am attempting to pass the function submitForm from formControl to index.js (Home). My goal: to remove form, upon successful form submission and show a success message. I have looked at several examples, but I am still missing something.

I am using Next.js, but I don't think the Next.js usage would be any different from react.js in this case. Also using react-hook-form, once again, I don't think RHF is interrupting the process.

**index.js Home view**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import { proteinArr, starchArr, greensArr} from '../utils'
import date from 'date-and-time';

export default function Home({ submitForm }) {

  const { register, handleSubmit, control, formState: { errors } } = useForm();


  const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
    e.target.reset()
    submitForm()
  }



  const now = new Date();
  let day = date.format(now, 'dddd').toLowerCase();
  // console.log(SaturdayArr)
  // console.log(date.format(now, 'dddd').toLowerCase())


  return (

    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((onSubmit))}>

        <div className={`${styles.home_card} card home_card `}>
          <div className="card-body">
            <h2 className={styles.title}>Pick your plate!</h2>




            <div className={`${styles.home_selectGroup} input-group mb-3`}>
              <div className="input-group-prepend">
                <span className="input-group-text" >Name</span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" className="form-control" {...register("name", { required: true })} placeholder="Order Name" aria-label="Order Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon" />
              {errors.name && <p>Order name is required</p>}
            </div>

            <div className={`${styles.home_selectGroup} input-group mb-3`}>
              <div className="input-group-prepend">
                <span className="input-group-text" >Email</span>
              </div>
              <input type="email" id="email" className="form-control" {...register("email")} placeholder="Email@provider.com" aria-label="Email" aria-describedby="basic-addon" />
            </div>

            <div className={`${styles.home_selectGroup} input-group mb-3`}>
              <div className="input-group-prepend">
                <span className="input-group-text" >Phone Number</span>
              </div>
              <input type="tel" id="phone" className="form-control" {...register("phone", { required: true })} placeholder="111-111-1111" aria-label="Phone Number" aria-describedby="basic-addon" />
              {errors.name && <p>Phone number is required</p>}
            </div>


            <div className={`${styles.home_selectGroup} input-group mb-3`}>
              <div className="input-group-prepend">
                <label className={`${styles.homeLabel} input-group-text`} htmlFor="inputGroupSelect01">Protein</label>
              </div>
              <select {...register("protein", { required: true })}
                className={`${styles.home_select} custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01`}
              >
                <option className={styles.home_option}>Choose...</option>
                {proteinArr && proteinArr.map((item) => <option key={item}>{item}</option>)}
              </select>
              {errors.protein && <p>Protein is required</p>}
            </div>

            <div className={`${styles.home_selectGroup} input-group mb-3`}>
              <div className="input-group-prepend">
                <label className={`${styles.homeLabel} input-group-text`} htmlFor="inputGroupSelect01">Greens</label>
              </div>
              <select

                {...register("greens", { required: 'select an option' })}
                className={`${styles.home_select} custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01`}>
                <option className={styles.home_option}>Choose...</option>
                {greensArr && greensArr.map((item) => <option key={item}>{item}</option>)}
              </select>
              {errors.greens && <p>Green is required</p>}
            </div>

            <div className={`${styles.home_selectGroup} input-group mb-3`}>
              <div className="input-group-prepend">
                <label className={`${styles.homeLabel} input-group-text`} htmlFor="inputGroupSelect01">Starch</label>
              </div>
              <select {...register("starch", { required: true })} className={`${styles.home_select} custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01`}>
                <option className={styles.home_option}>Choose...</option>

                {starchArr && starchArr.map((item) => <option key={item}>{item}</option>)}

              </select>
              {errors.starch && <p>Starch is required</p>}



            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-primary contact-form_button " type="submit">Submit My Order</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

    </>
  )
}
```

**FormControl**

```
import Home from '../../pages/index'
import { useState } from 'react';

const FormControl = () => {

    const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);

    function submitForm(){
        setIsSubmitted(true);
    }

    return (
        <div>
             {isSubmitted == false ? <Home submitForm={submitForm}/> : <h2>Your from was submitted</h2>}
        </div>
    );
}

export default FormControl;
```

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next.js is just logic on top of React so the way you interact with it is handled the same for both libraries.

However, pages in React and Next.js are both components but pages in Next.js have a lot of functionality added/injected, so you must treat them differently.

Because of this, you cannot just pass [props to pages](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages) in Next.js like you are as they will always be undefined. You can set page props via [getInitialProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps), [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation), [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering), in [_document](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document), or even in [_app](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app).

With that said, you can simplify your form status by using react-hook-form's [successful form submission](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/formstate) status.

```js
export default function Home() {
  const {formState: { isSubmitSuccessful } } = useForm();

  if(isSubmitSuccessful) return <h2>Your from was submitted</h2>;

  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((onSubmit))}>
   ...form stuff
  </form>
}
```

You could make the form it's own component too

Home page

```js
import HomeForm form './HomeForm'

export default function Home() {
 handleSubmit= () => {...submit logic}
 return <HomeForm onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
}
```

Home form component

```js
export default function HomeForm({ onSubmit }) {
  const {formState: { isSubmitSuccessful } } = useForm();

  if(isSubmitSuccessful) return <h2>Your from was submitted</h2>;

  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((onSubmit))}>
   ...form stuff
  </form>
}
```

Comment: I had time to look at this today and your solution put me on the correct path. Thanks for the valuable feedback!